How can I see frame keys of the material?
I forgot the key combination for it


You need to press i to create the default keyframe (K to choose the wanted transformations, ShiftK to set the default keyframe). In order to see the keyframe in the Dope Sheet, if you've activated the Only Show Selected option (image below), you need to select the object that has the material:

